# Filter records before Django admin renders a model data

Tags: python, django, django-admin

So, I have a model named foo.
My requirement is to show a filtered list of records on the admin dashboard for foo.
Basically, I want to filter the QuerySet even before admin renders the view for foo.

Is there a way to do this?

My environment: 
Django == 1.7,
Python == 2.7

I use Grappelli to render my admin site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        query = super(FooAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        filtered_query = query.filter(name='bar')
        return filtered_query
```

Comment: The method is called `get_queryset`, not `queryset`.

Comment: This solved my problem. I can now see a filtered query set for FooAdmin. 
I have another admin site and ModelAdmin for the same model. The problem is that, even though, I filtered the query set for one ModelAdmin, it filters both.

Comment: Solved it. My bad.

Comment: great answer, been looking for this in other places and couldn't find it cause I have a jwt token that is not from django xD

Answer (score 1):

For doing this, please read this
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset